# How does one host a Kohana installation from a subdirectory on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, kohana

I am attempting to host a Kohana installation on Nginx. The difference is that I am trying to serve it up from a subdirectory as opposed to the web root itself.

**The problem**: 
When trying to access the url, `http://myproject.tld/Project/Welcome`, I am given the error message: `No input file specified.`

Upon investigation, I noticed that this is in fact being rewritten as `http://myproject.tld/index.php/Project/Welcome/` when it should be `http://myproject.tld/Project/index.php/Welcome/`

as seen here:

```
2014/01/02 23:10:57 [debug] 20952#0: *30 http copy filter: 0 "index.php/Project/Welcome?"
2014/01/02 23:10:57 [debug] 20952#0: *30 http finalize request: 0, "index.php/Project/Welcome?" a:1, c:1
```

Now, I understand fully why it is happening. Because I am hosting from a subdirectory that will exist within the request_uri and is appended to the url rewrite. If I were serving from the document root this wouldn't be an issue. What I'm hoping is someone can point me in the correct direction for solving this particular hiccup.

**Setup Information**:

nginx/1.4.4

Kohana 3.3.1

**Server configuration**:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name mydomain.tld;

    access_log /home/<user>/logs/mydomain-access.log;
    error_log /home/<user>/logs/mydomain-error.log debug;

    # main root
    root   /home/<user>/domains/mydomain.tld;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        expires off;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    # Prevent access to hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location /Project/ {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ index.php$request_uri last;
    }

    location ~* \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param KOHANA_ENV development;
        fastcgi_cache off;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set up .htaccess and bootstrap.php properly (best to post the relevant parts of both if unsure)?

Comment: nginx doesn't utilize .htaccess rules the way apache does. What you see above in the server config is the equivalent to the htaccess rules. And yes, I have updated base_url in the bootstrap to point to this location.

Answer (score 0):

To get `http://myproject.tld/Project/index.php/Welcome/` rewriting you should configure Kohana in /application/bootstrap.php - `base_url` to `/Project/` in `Kohana::init()` block.